# C# Datetime add days with hours and minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I am able to create a DateTime object and initialize it adding days, like the following:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
```

The problem is the following: the output displays the hours and minutes always set to 00:00.

A found a dirty solution, which consists in concat a string generated by the following instruction:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

In this way I'm able to get the correct and current hours and minutes.

Is there a clean way to encode this information in the same DateTime variable?

Comment: `Today` and `Now` are different. This doesn't have anything to do with strings or formatting

Comment: `DateTime.Today` returns the date portion of the current date, with the time portion all set to `0`, while `DateTime.Now` returns both the current date and time. Just replace `Today` with `Now` in your original example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`

`DateTime.Now` is not dirty, and formatting it is not either

`DateTime.Now` gives you a DateTime variable.

The formatting `.ToString()` returns a string to format as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.Now as given below:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
```

It will give hours and minuts as well.